# Angular-cli: redirect after form submission

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

this is driving me crazy.

I have an angular app made with **angular-cli**.

I followed this tutorial to create a login:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

and have now a strange problem.

The login component doesn't redirect me to home, but to the same page:

/login?username=XXX&password=YYY

I use @angular/router ~3.1.0 . Any ideas????

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post your routes?